# Simplify function numerically in Sage

Tags: sagemath

When I have a function that is exact, such as:

```
x = var("x")
fnc = sqrt(2) * x
print(fnc)
```

And I want to resolve/approximate all those parts of the function which can be resolved numerically, how can I do this?

```
fnc.n()
```

does not work because it throws a TypeError, similarly does

```
float(fnc)
```

I've also tried all .simplify() variants, but neither do what I want. I simply want the output to be:

```
print(magic_function(fnc))
1.4142 * x
```

How can this be done?

Comment: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) is more appropriate for your question than MSE.

Comment: [Ask.SageMath](https://ask.sagemath.org/) would be a much more appropriate site for this question than any StackExchange site.